# How to transform entire pandas data frame in one hot representation?

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, dataframe

I want all the columns one hot encoded without the need of listing out the columns or apply one hot encode one by one. I know how to do it one column then another.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:: [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

`get_dummies` will only convert string columns and will keep numerical columns as it is. You can first convert categorical columns into string type and then apply get_dummies.

```
concated_dataset['1stFlrSF'] = concated_dataset['1stFlrSF'].astype("string")
pd.get_dummies(cacated_dataset)
```

Comment: Yeah then first convert all the columns you want to be one hot encoded into string type and then apply get_dummies on the whole dataframe.